# Help me solving this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

Someone can help me??
$$
\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6} 
$$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange. Please edit your question with any attempts or thoughts you have at answering your question. This helps people understand exactly what you need help with and shows that you are putting in an effort.

Comment: Thanks. Oh, ok I'm gonna edit it, :D

Comment: **Hint:** Consider $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{xy^3}{x^2+y^6}$ first setting $y = 0$, then setting $y = x^{1/3}$

Comment: Ahhh, makes sense. I've done now